# Flutter TreeGrid

Tags: flutter, treeview, treegrid

There are a "treegrid" widget in Flutter? I am searching something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

there are packages that provide that functionality, here are two:

https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_treeview

https://pub.dev/packages/tree_view